# multiple maven projects release against a common timestamp

Tags: maven, release

We have several projects undergoing, and there are dependencies relationships among them. All projects makes up a final software.

We set up a DEV build environment to do snapshots build by using LASTEST dependencies. Any change will trigger a snapshot build (jekins job) and all dependent's snapshot build will be triggered too, and so if any changes break some project, that project's own build will notify the owner.

The question is about the release. The DEV build is continuous, and we want to release EVERY project against certain timestamp when it was a GREEN dev build across all projects.

How to get such release process setup?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jenkins provides some Post-Build-Actions. You can use them to publish/archive every successfully built artifact to whereever you want.

Your Release-Job can take all the artifacts and deploy them. So you're sure all artifacts are from GREEN builds and is also independent from all the continuous jobs.

If you want to be really cool, do some smoke tests (e.g. is database connection working, external APIs working, etc) in the Release-Job as well.

best,
marco

Comment: Hi, Marco, thanks, we are trying to set it up as you mentioned. One thing is that, when on Day 3 our repo has been committed more changes, and we verified a DEV build on Day 1 was green and we want to release that snapshot build, how the repo release tags will be added?

Comment: Previously, we did releases and add the release tag to the repo, so whenever there is a release tag, that means all changes up to this tag got integrated into that release.

now we choose to directly promote a Green DEV Build to be a release, so I'm wondering how that release tag should be added. Today's tweaking is that we still add release tag to the HEAD, but in the tag, or change message, we added the change # against which this release was built.

Comment: Hm ok. That is a tricky deployment you're trying to build there ;) 
here is my idea for that:
- build a Packaging-Job that collects all artifacts and creates a new tag in your repo
- name the tag somehow time related
- build a Release-Job that takes the time of interest as a [parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)
- the Release-Job uses the tag with the given time to release the content. The Packaging-Job can be triggered either by crontab (e.g. once per hour) or after one of the Dependency-Jobs finished a build successfully. Is this fulfilling your needs?